# How to run celery workers with sequential task execution with "per-child" bounds

Tags: python, kubernetes, celery

The context is that I'm using kubernetes for parallelism and workload balancing, similar to [this](https://miguescri.com/post/2021-05-22-celery-hpa/).  Given this, it is desirable to have no concurrency within the celery workers -- we get that by  k8s horizontal scaling.  In addition, limiting each worker to sequential task processing ensures that the memory use is constrained.

Given this context, it seems sensible to use the `solo` pool option when starting the workers.  However, I am suspicious that keeping the  worker running for an arbitrarily long time and doing all of the work in the same process will result in gradual memory leakage that will cause a task execution to fail.

Celery provides options for starting the worker to address this memory (or other resource) leakage: `max-tasks-per-child, max-memory-per-child`; these restart the child processes (or threads) that actually do the processing work either periodically or when a memory threshold is reached.  The latter helps deal with packages/processes that leak memory.

The seemingly ideal solution would be to start the worker(s) like this:

```
python -m celery -A worker.app worker -P solo --max-memory-per-child 1048576 --max-tasks-per-child 10
```

That way, the worker (in a given pod), just processes tasks sequentially, but also restarts periodically (every 10 jobs) or if the memory bound is exceeded (1048576KiB) in order to ensure that all resources are returned to the OS.

However, I have my doubts that the "per-child" options have an effect on a solo worker --  Will the solo worker re-start if the bounds are exceeded or are these options only relevant for multi-process or multi-threaded workers? [the celery documentation is not helpful]

Overall my goals are this:

- Use `celery` for task distribution an processing
- Run the workers in separate kubernetes pods to take advantage of that system's ability to scale resources
- Have no concurrency in the celery workers so that the pod memory usage is stable and predictable,
- Protect against resource (memory) leakage to reduce the chance that tasks fail

how can I set up the celery workers to achieve this?

The "per-child" options look like a promising approach if there is a way to confirm that they operate correctly for a `solo` pool worker.

Comment: Good quiestion! - Another question is does Celery worker pre-fetch tasks in "solo" mode? I like your approach. I think it will work. Did you actually try it? That is the only way to find answers I am afraid...

Comment: @DejanLekic I'm going to try it soon.  Not 100% sure how to test whether the per-child options actually do anything.   If I'm understanding you right, pre-fetching is a problem with the kubenetes interaction.  I noticed that when there is one worker (in one pod) using a process pool (n=1) and multiple tasks are submitted that one worker will grab them all, at least until more pods spin up.   Hopefully `solo` will mitigate that, but I haven't tried solo yet.

Comment: I'm still concerned about leaking memory (or other resourdes)  in solo mode , and thus not being a good solution for production.

Comment: Then perhaps prefork with -c1 and -max-memory-per-child 1048576 --max-tasks-per-child 10 ?